# How to perform automated testing of an entire site after core changes?

Tags: updating, testing

I'm looking for a module which will test an entire site with each OS update, or Drupal core update. E.g. go through each node and let me know there are any 404 returned for JS or CSS files, broken links, any white screens of death, etc. And if possible if the response time of the site has drastically decreased.

I've done some search and can I only see references to [SimpleTest](https://www.drupal.org/project/simpletest) used or unit testing. I'm looking at using Selenium at the moment.

How are other people testing sites after a core changes?

Comment: Selenium works well for this.  It takes awhile to set up but in my case the investment has certainly been worth it.

Comment: I'd second the vote on Selenium; you can get your feet wet with the Selenium IDE to do basic testing really quickly and convert those tests/make more thorough and complex tests using Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/simpletest - it provides essentially the same testing API as the core D7 module and you still have to write the tests yourself. There is also http://drupal.org/project/simpletest_automator that apparently will help you 'record' your actions on a site into a SimpleTest for you.

Additional helpful links:

- http://drupal.org/project/selenium
- http://drupal.org/simpletest